# Splunk panel for calculating grater then operation

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-dashboard

Sharing the application log:

```
2021-08-25T20:45:17.382Z level=info module=xyz pid=45 message="queryAPI, Execution Time(ms):,617.195517, pId:45" 
2021-08-25T20:45:17.382Z level=info module=xyz pid=45 message="queryAPI, Execution Time(ms):,231.195517, pId:45"
```

Question: Find the total number of API's which took more then 500 ms in splunk dashboard?

Please share the splunk query to find out below data.

Expected output display in table of two column :
Delayd API-Name:   queryAPI 
Total occurences:     1

Comment: Do you already have any established fields?

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for asking . Only 2 columns should display .  API name and total number of slow response call.

Comment: that didn't answer @PM77-1's question, fregp :)   ....what fields do you already have extracted?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data:

> `2021-08-25T20:45:17.382Z level=info module=xyz pid=45 message="queryAPI, Execution Time(ms):,617.195517, pId:45"`
> `2021-08-25T20:45:17.382Z level=info module=xyz pid=45 message="queryAPI, Execution Time(ms):,231.195517, pId:45"`

Something like this should work:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp message=*
| rex field=message "(?<apiname>\w+).+\,(?<exectime>\d+\.\d+).+:(?<pid>\d+)$"
| where exectime>500
| stats values(exectime) as longtimes by apiname pid
```

I've assumed you have the field `message` already extracted, and have extracted `apiname`, `exectime`, and `pid` from the `message` field

https://regex101.com/r/YBKtFc/1

Comment: The regular expression not working with this message having doble quotes at the beginning and end .      message="queryAPI, Execution Time(ms):,231.195517, pId:45"   ..                    Can you help on getting the count of each API took more then 500 ? Thanks

Comment: @fregp - am I correct in understanding, then, that the `message` field is not already extracted?

Comment: Yes your right , i m trying to extract the fields and display records with respect to each API slowness. Can you please check on this

Comment: @fregp - just expand the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/IIH08U/1) like this: `| rex field=_raw "message[[:punct:]]+(?<apiname>\w+).+\,(?<exectime>\d+\.\d+).+:(?<pid>\d+)"`